# jquery Ajax post request gets cancelled

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Ajax POST request to a .NET server-side code and for some reason the success of my callback doesn't fire:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function () {
        var serializedLoginForm = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: serializedLoginForm,
            url: "https://localhost:44388/Login",
            success: function (result) {
                // doesn't get here
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Backend:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public IActionResult TestLogin(string test)
    {
        return Content($"{test}");
    }
}
```

It gets to the TestLogin Action, but then no response is returned to the front-end. Also when I inspect it with Chrome it says cancelled. Why?

Comment: Did you add an error method and see if that gets triggered?

Comment: Yes, it just says Error

Comment: So did you log what the error is? `success: function () { console.log(arguments); }`

Comment: I also faced this sort of issue some days ago 

You can do `public JsonResult TestLogin(string test)` and in return you can do `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Turned out I had a Chrome CORS extension turned on. Switching it off, solved the issue